# Xproc: passing a dynamic href to <p:http-request>

Tags: xml, xslt, xproc

I have a pipeline that runs an XSLT on the input, then doing a PUT of that result into a database via a `<p:http-request>` step.

The tricky bit here is that I need to build a dynamic href using metadata from the output of the `<p:xslt>` XML.

Pseudo code here of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
  <p:xslt name="XSLT1">
            <p:input port="stylesheet">
                <p:document href="XSLT-1.xslt" />
            </p:input>
        </p:xslt>

    <p:variable name="href" select="concat('http://localhost:8000/myRESTendpoint?uri=/mydb/', /*/@name, /*/@number,'.xml')"/>

        <p:sink />

        <p:insert position="first-child" match="c:body">
            <p:input port="source">
                    <p:inline>
                        <c:request 
                            href="{$href}" 
                            auth-method="basic" 
                            username="user" 
                            password="pw" 
                            method="put">
                            <c:body content-type="text/xml" >
                            </c:body>
                        </c:request> 
                    </p:inline>            
            </p:input>
            <p:input port="insertion">
                <p:pipe step="XSLT1" port="result" />        
            </p:input>
        </p:insert>

    <p:http-request  omit-xml-declaration="false" encoding="UTF-8">
       <p:input port="source"/>
    </p:http-request>
```

As you can see in the `<p:variable>` step, I'm trying to build a string and construct it with attribute values from the output XML of the `<p:xslt>` step and feed that into my `<c:request>` step's href option.

I've tried adding a `<p:attribute match>` step to alter the href attribute before the `<p:http-request>` but it doesn't grab the `/*/@name` and `/*/@number` values I need:

```
<p:add-attribute match="/c:request" attribute-name="href">
    <p:with-option name="attribute-value" select="concat('http://localhost:8000/myRESTendpoint?uri=/mydb/', /*/@name, /*/@number,'.xml')"/>
</p:add-attribute>
```

Answer (score 3):

Alright I was able to figure this out.

Looks like adding a `<p:add-attribute>` step was the right approach and the issue here was just an error in my Xpath...

```
<p:with-option name="attribute-value" select="concat('http://localhost:8000/myRESTendpoint?uri=/mydb/', /*/*/@name, /*/*/@number,'.xml')"/>
```

Since the PUT body is wrapped in a  element, I needed to go one more level down to reach the metadata I needed at the root element of my XML document (XSLT1 output), so my Xpath values needed to be updated to `/*/*/@name` and `/*/*/@number`.